# jQuery site does not show image after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and this code:

```
$(window).load(function()
{           
  var i =0;
  var j =0;
  var images = ['img/TopSlider/car_and_cycle.jpg', 'img/TopSlider/cafe.jpg'];
  var image = $('#box');

  var titles = ['Rent Car and Bikes', 'Cafes and Restaurants'];

  //Initial Background image setup
  image.css('background-image', 'url(img/TopSlider/cafe.jpg)');

  //Change image at regular intervals
  setInterval(function()
  {
      image.fadeOut(1000, function ()
      {
          image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
          image.fadeIn(1000);

          $("#text2").text(titles [j++]);
      });

      if(i == images.length)
      {
          i = 0;
          j = 0;
      }
   }, 5000);
});
```

but after some time (maybe 10 min), when I go back to the tab in Safri, I don't see the background image. But at start and maybe during 1 min it works perfect.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: I just use safari, I am not sure that there is console, how can I attach console? thank you for answer?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Side Note: You don't need `i` and `j`, you can get away with just one counter... just don't increment it until after you've set the title.

Comment: @tymeJV, awesome!!! even don't know about this great thing in safari, usually I use inspector in google chrome ) the issue i've checked: Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: @tymeJV but how it can be? ) at start everything works good

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander -- Is it the correct URL?

Comment: @entropic right point, but the issues seems does not connect to additional variable. just optimisation issue I think, also I noticed that if statement does not work if I call this function manually. it  is buggy with manually switching (by pressing button for example). i pushed in to the fadeOut and right now it works

Comment: That's why I clarified it as a side note :)

Comment: I can't understand how to system change this url because images are in the same directory when I refresh site, and after some time it starts to cause this error. I never delete folders or images on the local machine, but in some time it does not show the images. I can read the error log) but I don't understand why, so the resource in the same places, the js is the same, but time case an issue) maybe some safari issues?

Comment: yes just checked on google chrome everything works perfect